# Geth node accounts balances and contracts reset to 0 after 30,000 Blocks in POA private network

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, geth-debugging, geth-clique

This is my geth node script

```
geth --datadir /root/data/data/ --networkid 1567134 --bootnodes enode://44a383ff2c8a78da1131ac82a4513b34de177103017f07c42098c53aad43bc3fd99f62d72d827349eb503f0054fec7683a7db36fc65f9d1238950f70bc4dba97@0.0.0.0:0?discport=8545 --cache=4096 --syncmode=full --gcmode=archive --http --http.addr "0.0.0.0" --ws --ws.addr "0.0.0.0" --ws.port "8546" --allow-insecure-unlock --ws.origins "*" --http --allow-insecure-unlock --http.corsdomain "*" --http.vhosts "*" --http.api "db, eth, net, web3, personal" --http.port "8545" --nodiscover --unlock 0xF122afAf3BEdae6E062Aa18e892ed8c0C9****** --password /root/data/pass.txt --mine --miner.threads 2
```

I run my geth node yesterday and it reached 22,000 blocks yesterday. And then I open and check my node today, data was reset including balances, contracts and blocks now it 6,000.

Is there any problems related to this that already solved? I been running geth for almost 1 month and I encountered the same problem. balances and always gone and blocks are reset.

NOTE:IM RUNNING THIS GETH NODE USING VPS UBUNTU OS & THIS IS FOR PRIVATE BLOCKCHAIN NETWORK

Comment: It is quite strange. I suggest to check the geth log, perhaps increase the log level, it could be a hardware issue with the VPS. Also, using insecure-lock might cause a bot or hacker accessing geth's console and crashed the node.

Comment: Im using insecure-unlock because of unlocking account. I f I disregard the unlock account with my command and unlock it manually using console, after I exit the console. The wallet will be lock again. Is there a way to unlock account not including -unlock in -flag commands?

Comment: Before doing anything I'd check if there's something in geth's log. There are a few simple solutions, like using a firewall and allow only your IP, using nginx as proxy in front of the http requests, etc.